# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 causes bootloop until BIOS goes into failed boot mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have been running a dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 for about a month now. 9/10 times I boot the PC I have no problems and I am presented with the grub menu after I see my BIOS logo screen. However, sometimes randomly the BIOS logo screen will fail to load and send my PC into a boot loop. I have to force it off using the PC power button, and after turning it on it eventually goes into bios and presents me with a boot failure prompt. If I go into BIOS and change nothing and reboot the grub menu pops up and everything magically works again. I was wondering if anyone knew what the case might be as I have set all my MOBO settings to UEFI and disabled CSM mode. The failure to boot also happens at random and I have a feeling it occurs during the hand off from the BIOS to the grub launcher.

Comment: First thing to do is update the UEFI if there's an update released. Next is check the drive where the EFI partition resides for error and general health, a failure to read it  causes all sorts of problems in POST. Last but not least, make sure Fast Startup is disabled in  Windows.

Comment: Fast boot is disabled in Windows, and EFI partition is healthy. Might have to update the BIOS to see if that fixes it then.